# Greasemonkey | поиск элемента в Div и нажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, html5, вконтакте, greasemonkey

Вконтакте есть моя группа и я пишу скрипт для приглашения на встречи некоторых ее участников (список имен, или ID)

Как найти нужный элемент по содержимому  тега href= и нажать кнопку находящуюся в родительском Div?

```html
<div class="friends_user_row clear_fix" id="random">

  <div class="friends_photo_wrap" onmouseover="uiPhotoZoom.over(this, random)">
    <a class="friends_photo _online" href="/id123456"><img class="friends_photo_img" alt="иван иванов" src="https://pp.me/123.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="friends_controls">
  <button class="flat_button button_small button_wide" onclick="return Friends.inviteToGroup(this, random, random, 0, 'random')">Выслать приглашение</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: клик на кнопку должен быть автоматическим, через скритп??

Comment: клик  через скритп

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i=0; i < res.length; i++)
{
    if(res[i].href == "http://localhost/id123456");
    {
        let bt = res[i].parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.flat_button');
        Friends.inviteToGroup(bt, random, random, 0, 'random')
    }
}
```